# $project: Is it possible to access a property of an expression result in just one single stage?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Is there any way to carry out the following operation in just one `$project` stage?

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
    {
        $project : {
            firstEmail : { $arrayElemAt : ["$emails", 0] }
        }
    },
    {
        $project : {
            domain : "$firstEmail.domain"
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) operator:

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
    {
        $project : {
            domain : {
                $let: {
                    vars: { firstEmail: { $arrayElemAt : ["$emails", 0] } },
                    in: "$$firstEmail.domain"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_dcxV9rCCQF)

Answer (score 3):

When working with array of objects, you can automatically get array of objects's properties with the dot notation.
So the following will perfectly work :

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
    {
        $project : {
            domain: { $arrayElemAt : ["$emails.domain", 0] }
        }
    }, 
])
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KahjcygCqsI)

Comment: Whoah! That's completely counter-intuitive but I can see it really works in this case as well :) I like it better in this case because it's so concise. Now I want to accept both answers but I can't :( I'll keep mickl's answer since it's more generic and works not only with arrays. Thank you so much!