# MongoDB aggregation: How to return an object property from an object in an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an array in the aggregation pipeline. I am using `$arrayElemAt` and `$filter` to get an object from an array. But I want to go further an return on object property only not the whole object.

```
    newObj: {
        "$arrayElemAt":[
            {$filter: {
                input: "$myBeautifulArray",
                as: "myBeautiful",
                cond: { $and: [
                   { $eq: [ "$$myBeautiful.property1", req.body.someValue] },
                ] }
            }},
            0
        ]
    },'
    // The desired output is to return only an object property value as opposed to the whole object.
```

I know I can add new field and use dot notation to access my object property but I want to do this process in my `$project` pipeline. And I do not think you can access a property made in the `$project` stage in the same`$project` stage. How can I achieve my desired result?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60287936/project-is-it-possible-to-access-a-property-of-an-expression-result-in-just-on/60288150#60288150 ?

Comment: @mickl yes it does. Much appreciated.